# javaScript issue in IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, contains

I have an MVC3 C# .Net web app.  I am firing a javaScript method of a submit button on the onclick event.  It works just fine in Firefox, I see the confirm box, but not in IE 8.  In IE it is always returning true and not showing the confrim box. Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function DoCopy() {
      return confirm(($("#myField").val().contains(";" + $("#myOtherField").val() + ";")));
    }
</script>
```

Here is the button:

```
<input type="submit" id="thePageSubmit" name="Command" value="Save" onclick="return DoCopy();" />
```

I am using jQuery but even when I use straight javaScript (document.forms[0].elements["myField"]) it works in Firefox but not IE.  Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly are you expecting the confirm box to contain?

Comment: oh, and for the record, this code doesn't appear to work in Chrome either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at this link: It's not compatible in IE
[string.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)

[image: Compatibility]